# O que é programação orientada a agentes?

Tags: paradigma-de-programação

Temos alguns paradigmas de programação bem conhecidos, porém bati de frente com esse paradigma e me surgiu algumas dúvidas:

- Onde é aplicado?
- Existe algum exemplo de onde já foi utilizado com sucesso?
- Qual a diferença da orientação a objetos X orientação a agentes?

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta interessante. Aqui está um framework para desenvolver simulações baseada em agentes: http://repast.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, no encontro trocando umas figurinhas com o Luiz Vieira ele citou e fiquei bem interessado.

Comment: @cantoni, vou dar uma olhada nesse framework

Comment: É bem bacana @WellingtonAvelino. Já fiz algumas coisas nele, mas tem bastante tempo.

Comment: Boa pergunta +1

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Orientação a Agentes é o termo que se usa pra descrever a forma de pensar na arquitetura de software em que as entidades computacionais de maior interesse são chamados de "agentes" (e não "objetos" ou "serviços"). Como [o colega @FranciscoMariaCalisto já bem colocou em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80617/73), esse paradigma se iniciou na Inteligência Artificial Distribuída, uma subárea da IA que visa resolver problemas cuja complexidade decorre de um caráter de distribuição funcional ou física.

> Só por curiosidade, há quem argumente que a própria Orientação a
>   Objetos também se iniciou com a IA (há um bom tempo, entre as décadas
>   de 60 e 70) quando era grande a preocupação com *representação de
>   conhecimento*. Os [*frames*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(artificial_intelligence)) (estereótipos de situações do mundo
>   real) são, essencialmente, objetos com seus atributos (nesse conceito
>   então chamados de *slots*).

A principal característica desse paradigma está no fato de que agentes são entidades autônomas que têm um objetivo próprio. Esse objetivo, naturalmente, é dado por um projetista, mas o agente vai buscar atingí-lo da melhor forma possível (algo que na IA é chamado de *racionalidade*). O nome "agente" vem dessa autonomia, no sentido de que essa entidade age em prol de outro alguém (semelhante a quando um artista fala que tem um agente).

Esse modelo de agência muda algumas coisas na forma como um sistema implementado com esse paradigma funciona. Em todas as orientações (isto é, na orientação a objetos, a serviços e a agentes), a resolução do problema decorre da troca de mensagens (invocação de métodos, por quaisquer meios). Porém:

- Na Orientação a Objetos, todas as entidades (os objetos) são desenvolvidos essencialmente pelo mesmo projetista. Mesmo que uma biblioteca externa seja utilizada, o projetista tem total conhecimento do funcionamento dos objetos nela contida, precisando se preocupar por exemplo com o estado de uma transação (inicializar a biblioteca, "comitar" depois de alterar algo, etc). Quando objetos trocam mensagens entre si, as respostas possíveis envolvem o retorno de algo ou uma indicação de erro, mas uma invocação é sempre realizada (executada) pelo objeto de destino.
- Na Orientação a Serviços, as entidades (serviços) não são necessariamente desenvolvidos pelo mesmo projetista. Um projetista pode utilizar os serviços criados e publicados por outros, focando seu interesse no conteúdo da resposta, e (de forma geral) não precisa se preocupar com qualquer estado que decorra desse pedido (não há "comit" pendente - um serviço solicita a realização de algo pelo outro que simplesmente o faz). Quando serviços trocam mensagens entre si, as respostas possíveis também envolvem o retorno de algo ou uma indicação de erro, e a chamada também é sempre realizada pelo serviço de destino.
- Na Orientação a Agentes, as entidades (agentes) não são necessariamente desenvolvidos pelo mesmo projetista. Mas o foco de interesse não é na resposta, e sim alcançar o objetivo local do agente (realizar a tarefa X). Mas não há qualquer relação de obrigatoriedade em responder uma mensagem enviada. Por exemplo, o agente A pode mandar uma mensagem ao agente B ("invocar" um método ou requisitar um serviço), e a sua resposta pode também ser um resultado qualquer ou um retorno de erro. Mas, a mensagem pode simplesmente *ser ignorada* pelo agente B caso ele julgue que não lhe convém, naquele momento, gastar tempo respondendo a ela.

Essa distinção é sutil, mas permite a emergência (no sentido de surgimento) de comportamentos não planejados pelo projetista, o que é muito útil na resolução de problemas complexos.

A arquitetura geral de um agente é também resultado da unificação de várias áreas da IA, e por isso considera que os agentes são entidades que percebem o ambiente onde estão imersos (eles têm sensores - algo equivalente a atributos dinâmicos, isto é, que se auto atualizam) e atuam nesse ambiente para se aproximar de seus objetivos individuais (eles têm atuadores - algo equivalente a métodos, mas que eles mesmo executam). Alguns atuadores são relacionados à comunicação com outros agentes (computacionais ou humanos). O gráfico abaixo, do livro [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), ilustra essa arquitetura geral:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse paradigma ainda não é tão popular no mercado profissional, muito embora seja usado por grandes empresas (o Google é a mais notável) para resolver problemas de complexidade distribuída. Ele também é bastante usado em jogos digitais, para implementar a IA dos NPCs (*Non-Playable Characters*).

Dois exemplos de sistemas que utilizam esse paradigma:

- Certa vez no mestrado vi uma palestra de um pesquisador alemão que mencionou que o sistema de controle aéreo de Berlin tem um sistema experimental baseado em agentes (infelizmente não tenho mais a referência). Há agentes para cada elemento de interesse do sistema: os aviões, as escadas rolantes do aeroporto, as esteiras de bagagem, os caminhões de combustível, etc. Tais agentes se comunicam tentando atingir seus objetivos com a ajuda de outros (o avião solicita abastecimento aos caminhões, e estes negociam com os aviões segundo proximidade, tempo para partida, etc). O sistema é executado juntamente com o sistema oficial (feito em orientação a objetos) porque ainda não há confiança no comportamento emergente desse paradigma (e se o agente em um avião decidir por decolar porque achou que era o melhor a fazer para alcançar seu objetivo, mas ignorou outros objetivos importantes externos, como segurança de outros aviões na pista?).
- Há [um sistema](http://front.cc.nctu.edu.tw/Richfiles/10004-GetPDF.aspxgetpdf.pdf) que foi construído de forma a utilizar agentes para identificar e validar, em imagens de otólitos de peixes (otólitos são concreções de carbonato de cálcio presentes no aparelho vestibular do ouvido interno dos vertebrados e que contêm anéis indicativos da idade estimada de um animal) anéis concêntricos alternados em intensidades claras e escuras e de formato e de largura variáveis. Os anéis servem para estimar a idade do peixe. Os agentes são especializados em anéis claros e escuros, e observam a intensidade da área angular à frente e a proximidade a outros agentes para se moverem e seguir os anéis. Um anel é validado se um agente consegue retornar ao seu ponto de partida.

Apesar de ser mais usado na área acadêmica, esse paradigma já está bem mais popular hoje do que há alguns anos (quando fiz meu mestrado nisso). Há época, já havia algumas metodologias de desenvolvimento sob esse paradigma. As mais notáveis são a [CommonKADS](http://teaching-wiki.sti2.at/uploads/9/93/06_Intelligent_Systems-CommonKADS.pdf) e a [GAIA](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/nrj/download-files/tosem03.pdf).

Também existem inúmeros arcabouços (*frameworks*) e linguagens para auxiliar no desenvolvimento de sistemas orientados a agentes. Exemplos notáveis são o [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com/), o [Jadex](http://www.activecomponents.org/bin/view/About/Features), e o [Jason](http://jason.sourceforge.net/wp/) em Java, e o [CAF](http://actor-framework.org/) em C++. Mas [há muitas outros](http://agentprogramming.com/agent-platforms/).

Comment: Eu só me recordava do exemplo do aeroporto de Berlin, mas não tinha entendido direito como funcionava, muito bom!

Comment: Bela resposta Luiz Vieira! A parte que me fascina nesse paradigma são os comportamentos emergentes e que surgem de maneira (muitas vezes) inesperada.

Comment: Pra quem quiser começar a brincar com esse paradigma, eu sugiro *fortemente* baixar o JADE. É open-source, em Java, e tem um arquitetura muito fácil de usar (você programa diretamente os comportamentos/behaviours dos agentes). Além disso, ele já tem toda uma infraestrutura pronta pra muitas coisas bacacas (entre elas, agentes móveis: você roda o serviço em várias máquinas, e os agentes podem "migrar" entre esses nós conforme seus planos requisitarem).

Answer (score 17):

Quando falamos em Agentes geralmente estamos a falar no âmbito da Inteligência Artificial, que neste caso, mais propriamente da [Inteligência Artificial Distribuída](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelig%C3%AAncia_artificial_distribu%C3%ADda).

> A Inteligência Artificial Distribuída (IAD), com um enfoque diferente
>   da Inteligência Artificial (IA) tradicional, tenta dividir um problema
>   em problemas pequenos e mais simples. Estes sistemas desenvolvidos,
>   utilizando a técnica da Inteligência Artificial Distribuída, podem
>   resolver problemas fisicamente distribuídos, que podem parecer
>   complexos, como uma rede de transportes em que existem diversos
>   elementos de transporte, assim como pontos de distribuição. É mais
>   intuitivo analisar este problema de forma distribuída.

No Paradigma de Programação Orientada a Agentes, onde um Programa é projectado e desenvolvido usando vários Agentes que se dá o nome de Sistemas Multiagente (SMA). Por este motivo o desenvolvimento de Software nesta gama obrigou a criação e pesquisa do novo Paradigma onde o software seria produzido com rigor, qualidade, desempenho e optimização, desta forma, tal requer o uso de metodologias, modelos e arquitecturas, assim como outros, para facilitar o desenvolvimento dentro do âmbito.

Deixo aqui um [Artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-paradigma-orientado-a-agentes/28791) interessante para ler.

Respondendo às suas questões:

- A Programação Orientada a Agentes é aplicada em Inteligência Artificial;
- Existem vários exemplos onde a metodologia está a ser usada com enorme sucesso:

  - Controle e automação;
  - Telecomunicações;
  - Sistemas de Transporte;
  - Jogos;
- Em relação à Programação Orientada a Objectos o **conceito** não tem nada a ver com a Programação Orientada a Agentes, apesar de POA poder ser implementado usando o paradigma Orientado a Objectos, falamos de coisas, que mesmo se complementando, são em Teoria distintas. Ou seja, POA pode usar POO mas são conceitos diferentes.

Comment: Muito bom Francisco, gostei da explicação +1.

Comment: Obrigado @WellingtonAvelino

Comment: Pela sua resposta e do Luiz, estão sendo bastante esclarecedoras.

Comment: Só não concordo muito com o último parágrafo. :) A Orientação a Agentes é só uma forma diferente de pensar o problema. Mas o mecanismo básico dos agentes pode ser implementados com Orientação a Objetos. As linguagens de programação são distintas mesmo, mas no fundo é o mesmo argumento entre a orientação estruturada e orientada a objetos: se alguém quiser, pode programar OO com C puro. Só não é muito eficiente, porque C++ já tem um monte de coisa pronta para o paradigma OO. :)

Comment: Tem razão @LuizVieira não me expressei correctamente. Queria apenas sublinhar que são conceitos diferentes e acabei por dizer que nada tinham a ver, o que não é verdade. Já editei a resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto Entendi, e concordo. Obrigado a você por ter se preocupado em editar. :)