# O que é inteligência artificial?

Tags: inteligência-artificial

1. Qual a definição de inteligência artificial?

A pergunta à primeira vista parece falta de vontade de pesquisar por aí afora, mas uma lida nos primeiros links que encontrei no Google me deixaram com mais dúvidas do que eu tinha antes de começar a estudar sobre o assunto.

A [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelig%C3%AAncia_artificial) me deu algumas definições e o [TecMundo](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/intel/1039-o-que-e-inteligencia-artificial-.htm) que foi o primeiro link que o buscador me retornou não me passou credibilidade por não citar fontes.

2. Partindo de uma definição como esta:

> *"sistemas que pensam como um humano"*

Seria correto dizer que todo sistema que afirme que 2+2 = 4 é um sistema com "inteligência artificial"?

Comment: Assita Ex-Machina. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0470752/ O Melhor.

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é programação orientada a agentes?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80614/3117)

Comment: Se você olhar a resposta aceita verá que a IA deu origem à programação orientada a agentes. Não estou dizendo que sua pergunta é duplicada, só que acho que a leitura de um tópico pode complementar a do outro. Isso pode auxiliar que aparecer por aqui (ou lá) e quiser saber um pouco mais sobre o assunto.

Comment: Tem uma safra de filmes dos últimos 2 anos que exploram essa inquietação humana de não saber exatamente o que é IA e seu significado muito além do 2+2. O [Chappie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1823672/) é figura demais. O Ex Machina, citado acima, trata de hormônios e tem bastante adrenalina. E o [Her](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1798709/) nos apresenta os OSs do futuro. . . . E, claro, o imortal, qualquer livro do mestre [Philip K. Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick)

Comment: Só eu que lembrei do [AI - Inteligência Artificial](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/)?

Comment: Recentemente publiquei um artigo e achei legal compartilhar aqui também. Você vai conseguir identificar todas as aplicações que utilizam inteligência artificial.
“Como eu sei se isso aqui é uma IA?” O método IAC parte do pressuposto de 5 perguntas básicas. A aplicação ou dispositivo que você está utilizando consegue:
Ver? Ouvir? Ler? Mover? Formar processos lógicos? Essas são as 5 perguntas principais para você identificar uma IA. As respostas para você identificar cada uma está no artigo: Fonte: https://turing.academy/metodo-inteligencia-artificial/

Answer (score 24):

### Uma breve introdução

O primeiro trabalho hoje reconhecido como pertencente à área de Inteligência Artificial (IA) foi realizado por [Warren McCulloch e Walter Pitts em 1943](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~coquand/AUTOMATA/mcp.pdf). Esse trabalho foi baseado em três fontes/assuntos-base:

- o conhecimento da fisiologia básica e da função dos neurônios no cérebro (um assunto com origem na Ciência Cognitiva)
- a análise formal da [lógica proposicional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_proposicional) (um assunto com origem na Filosofia e na Matemática)
- e a Teoria da Computação de [Alan Turing](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) (o assunto que deu origem à Ciência da Computação)

Mas o termo "Inteligência Artificial" somente foi cunhado em 1956 pelo cientista de computação [John McCarthy](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McCarthy), em uma conferência que teve também a participação de [Marvin Minsky](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_Minsky) (co-fundador do [MIT](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instituto_de_Tecnologia_de_Massachusetts) e um dos principais teoristas da IA). McCarthy tinha muito interesse em lógica, um ramo que é intuitivamente ligado à manipulação e ao raciocínio simbólico dos seres humanos, e por isso teve o interesse de estudar a forma como *aspectos da inteligência* (como criatividade, auto-aperfeiçoamento e uso da linguagem, por exemplo) poderiam ser reproduzidos em sistemas computacionais (consequentemente, de forma "artificial").

> Para mais detalhes da história da IA, consulte o Capítulo 1 do livro
>   [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), de Stuart Russell and
>   Peter Norvig. Esse é o livro mais utilizado em cursos de IA nas
>   principais Universidades do mundo (sendo também a minha sugestão para
>   quem deseja se aprofundar no assunto), e seus autores são ilustres -
>   especialmente [Peter Norvig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Norvig), que atualmente é Diretor de Pesquisas
>   na Google Inc.

Deve ser possível perceber que nos primórdios da IA havia uma grande preocupação com o entendimento e a reprodução da inteligência em seres humanos. Porém, uma primeira grande dificuldade é justamente definir o que é inteligência. Por um lado, pode-se dizer que inteligência é o conjunto de capacidades cognitivas de um ser humano, incluindo comunicação, percepção e pensamento abstrato. Mas, por outro lado, outros seres sem toda essa capacidade também são inteligentes.

Os chimpanzés são reconhecidamente muito inteligentes, pois apesar de não terem toda a nossa capacidade cognitiva ainda assim são capazes de [fazer planos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9RVyieNhNo) e [comunicar intenções](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K03R14FzPGg) (e sob certos aspectos, [poder-se-ia dizer que são até mais inteligentes do que os humanos modernos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hkq343NS3nM) hehehehe). A proximidade genética *não é a questão aqui*, pois os corvos também são muito inteligentes, sendo capazes de fazer [planos elaborados](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpgCQj-sgqk) e aprender com tentativa e erro para se [adaptar ao ambiente](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGPGknpq3e0). Ou seja, inteligência não envolve apenas raciocínio abstrato e planejamento, mas também reatividade e adaptação. Uma mosca pode ser considerada inteligente no sentido de que é capaz de evitar com sucesso a maioria dos seus ataques com o chinelo.

Nesse sentido, os estudos da IA eventualmente evoluiram para outros conceitos. O artigo [*Elephants Don't Play Chess*](https://msujaws.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/elephants-dont-play-chess/) (Elefantes não Jogam Xadrez), de Rodney Brooks, que deu origem à [Arquitetura de Subsunção](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsumption_architecture) amplamente utilizada em robôs da academia e da indústria, pregam que inteligência é algo mais simples, e cuja complexidade advém das diversas formas de comportamento onde ela é expressa. Assim, na IA - como ciência aplicada - **o conceito *ideal* de inteligência é a racionalidade: fazer o melhor sempre que possível**.

Apesar de originalmente a IA ter um foco muito forte na reprodução das capacidades humanas, hoje acredita-se que ela tem um objetivo mais aplicado (a discussão sobre a IA fraca e forte [da resposta do colega @mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86884/73) trata justamente dessa dualidade de intenções). Russell e Norvig, em seu livro, fazem uma comparação interessante:

> O objetivo da Engenharia Aeronáutica não é criar máquinas voadoras que
>   sejam perfeitas a ponto de enganar aos pássaros, mas sim de criar
>   máquinas voadoras que façam isso (voem) da melhor maneira possível.
>   Também o objetivo da IA, como uma disciplina de engenharia, não
>   deveria ser criar máquinas que agem tão perfeitamente a ponto de
>   enganar aos humanos. Mas sim de criar máquinas que são capazes de se
>   adaptar para resolver problemas complexos.

Isso não quer dizer que estudar IA não sirva para nos ajudar a também entender as nossas capacidades biológicas. Afinal de contas, a IA envolve diversas áreas, entre elas o **Processamento de Linguagem Natural**, a **Representação de Conhecimento**, o **Raciocínio Automatizado**, o **Aprendizado (de Máquina)**, a **Visão (de Computador)** e a **Movimentação e Manipulação de Objetos** (isto é, ter um corpo físico e se reconhecer como um agente no mundo, algo importante para a **Robótica**).

### Respondendo às suas perguntas

**1. Qual a definição de inteligência artificial?**

A Inteligência Articial é uma área de desenvolvimento que tangencia a Ciência da Computação na construção de sistemas computacionais capazes de resolver problemas complexos e a Engenharia na construção dos sensores e atuadores necessários para que os agentes dito inteligentes sejam de fato racionais (no sentido de que buscam fazer o melhor sempre que possível). Por isso, a arquitetura geral de um sistema inteligente (dito um agente, já que ele existe em um ambiente, percebe as alterações nesse ambiente - suas e de outros agentes - e atua/age para mudá-lo na tentativa de atingir seus objetivos) é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A Engenharia entra na construção dos sensores e atuadores do agente (e também do ambiente, em muitos cenários), e a Ciência da Computação entra na construção do mecanismo de decisão (a caixinha com a interrogação ali dentro).

**2. Partindo de uma definição como esta "sistemas que pensam como um humano", seria correto dizer que todo sistema que afirme que 2+2 = 4 é um sistema com "inteligência artificial"?**

Não, porque realizar o cálculo `2 + 2 = 4` não requer "pensamento", principalmente o raciocínio como nós humanos fazemos. A sua calculadora é capaz de fazer esse cálculo apenas com operações lógicas simples. Foque nesse símbolo: "2". Isso pode significar qualquer coisa, ou pode não significar nada. Qual é a diferença entre "2", "II", ".." ou duas pedras no meio de uma cratera em Marte? O pensamento só ocorre no momento em que alguém (ou algo) dá significado a um símbolo ou uma operação.

Nesse aspecto, um sistema computacional que gere "4" como resposta a duas entradas de "2" e "2" é meramente um programa. Foi programado para tal e provavelmente vai dar algum erro se ao menos uma das entradas for diferente (`".." + 2` dá quanto? Provavelmente erro de *type mismatch*! :) ). Um sistema inteligente busca fazer o melhor que conseguir. Ele não vai meramente dar erro ou "quebrar" (*crash*), pois vai gerar um resultado que pode ser momentaneamente ruim até que ele tenha a possibilidade de se adaptar para essa nova entrada (talvez solicitando a resposta correta para outro agente que a saiba, por exemplo).

Comment: `".." + 2 dá quanto? Provavelmente erro de type mismatch!` A não ser que tente fazê-lo em PHP :)

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Nesse caso, dá quanto? :)

Comment: É 2, hehe @LuizVieira

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Seria mais curioso se desse `".."`. :)

Comment: Gostei desse último exemplo! O interessante é que um humano não só tentaria chegar a uma resposta correta, como se preocuparia em "como *comunicar* essa resposta de forma que o agente consumidor entenda" ou talvez se perguntaria "é melhor dar uma resposta ou comunicar ao autor da pergunta que há um problema? E como?" etc.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Exatamente. E o mais interessante é que, quando acontece com humanos, a escolha do que talvez seja o melhor a fazer depende também de muita informação de contexto e de senso comum. O primeiro é até possível de se colocar em um sistema computacional. O difícil é o segundo... :)

Answer (score 15):

Não há um consenso em relação à melhor definição para "Inteligência Artificial" (ou "Inteligência Computacional", outro termo bastante usado). Por exemplo, [uma definição](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124121535) bastante simples porém que não diz muita coisa é:

> Inteligência Artificial é o empreendimento de construção de um artefato inteligente.

Entretanto, há controvérsias no que pode ser considerado "inteligente" ou não:

- Inteligente é aquilo que um humano faz bem?
- Outras formas de vida também possuem inteligência? (ex.: uma formiga é "burra", mas uma colônia de formigas se comporta de forma surpreendentemente sofisticada)
- Que **aspectos** de um ser humano são necessários uma máquina possuir para ela ser considerada inteligente? (é necessário, por exemplo, ela ter visão e audição, ou basta ter capacidade de raciocínio?)

Etc. Por fim, há a questão de saber se a máquina precisa ser inteligente de fato ou apenas *parecer* inteligente (ver "I.A. Forte" vs. "I.A. Fraca"). O ["quarto chinês"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarto_chin%C3%AAs) é um experimento mental interessante que ilustra essa distinção.

Quanto a um sistema que afirma que 2 + 2 = 4, dizer se ele é "inteligente" depende muito de com quais **premissas** ele trabalha, e que **proecessos** ele usou para se chegar ao resultado. É um computador "normal" - com uma estrutura de dados numérica e uma operação de adição *built-in*? Então eu diria que "não", o computador apenas está executando uma ordem bem específica que foi programada na sua "essência". Por outro lado, se esse computador [recebeu somente os axiomas básicos da matemática](http://what-when-how.com/Tutorial/topic-4a6og/Robots-Unlimited-Life-in-a-Virtual-Age-234.html) (tipo teoria de conjuntos, etc) e foi capaz de "redescobrir a aritmética", a ponto de não só responder a essa pergunta mas também de chegar a conclusões [corretas] que o próprio autor não previa (como ["o oposto de números primos"](http://what-when-how.com/Tutorial/topic-4a6og/Robots-Unlimited-Life-in-a-Virtual-Age-235.html)), então eu diria sim que ele demonstrou inteligência.

Comment: a resposta do [quarto luminoso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Churchland#Quarto_Luminoso) me deixou ainda mais na dúvida

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Eu também estou confuso, nunca tinha visto isso, mas minha interpretação é a seguinte: se o homem dentro do quarto fosse de fato capaz de mover o ímã trilhões de vezes por segundo, isso seria indistinguível para alguém do lado de fora de uma luminosidade "real". Então não sei exatamente o que esse experimento "desprova", teria de ler o material original para ver se faço algum sentido disso...