# Qual é a definição de Aprendizado de Máquina (Machine Learning)?

Tags: terminologia, inteligência-artificial, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Fiz essa pergunta [Algoritmo para detectar nudez com boa precisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104656/algoritmo-para-detectar-nudez-com-boa-precis%C3%A3o)  aqui no site e algumas pessoas citaram algumas coisas sobre *Aprendizado de Máquina (Machine Learning)*.

Pelo que foi dito entre um comentário e outro a respeito do assunto, deu a entender (bem superficialmente) que é uma forma de uma máquina "aprender" a ter um comportamento a partir de dados pré-definidos.

Gostaria de uma explanação mais detalhada a respeito do assunto:

- O que seria o Aprendizado de Máquina (Machine Learning)?
- Ele está relacionado à (ou é uma forma de) Inteligência Artificial?
- Que exemplo mais simples podemos citar a respeito desse assunto?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> O que seria o Machine Learning?

*Machine Learning* pode ser traduzido simplesmente como *Aprendizado (ou Aprendizagem) de Máquina (ou Computacional)*. O termo se refere a um enorme conjunto de técnicas que visam construir sistemas computacionais cujo comportamento seja definido com base em *dados existentes*. Como o comportamento do sistema não seria diretamente programado, mas sim adaptado de algum "conhecimento" previamente adquirido, essa abordagem teria similaridade com a forma como animais (entre eles, nós humanos) aprendem com a experiência.

> Ele está relacionado à (ou é uma forma de) Inteligência Artificial?

Certamente que sim. Definir concisamente o que é inteligência é uma tarefa árdua, pois a inteligência tem diferentes aspectos importantes. O reconhecimento e manipulação de símbolos, a linguagem e a comunicação verbal e escrita, a visão, o planejamento, a adaptação com base em experiências (também chamada de aprendizado), etc. A Inteligência Artificial, como sub-área da Engenharia/Ciência da Computação, tem várias preocupações, e uma delas é simular a adaptação e o aprendizado para a resolução de problemas complexos. Se você observar o diagrama do modelo geral de um agente inteligente a seguir, e que eu mencionei originalmente na [minha resposta sobre o que é inteligência artificial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87014/73), perceberá que aquela caixinha com a interrogação precisa conter toda a "lógica" que permitiria ao agente perceber as mudanças no mundo com os sensores (*sensors*) e decidir a melhor forma de manipular o mundo segundo suas intenções com os atuadores (*effectors*):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Certamente, aprendizado estaria ali, sendo um importante aspecto da inteligência (artificial).

> Que exemplo mais simples podemos citar a respeito desse assunto?

Da mesma forma que é difícil definir o que é inteligência, também é difícil definir concisamente o que é aprendizado. A noção mais trivial (e que interessa no escopo da Ciência da Computação) é de que aprendizado é a capacidade de se adaptar com a experiência. Um sistema computacional inteligente seria capaz de aprendizado se alterasse seu comportamento conforme observasse os efeitos das ações próprias e de outros no ambiente em que atua. O oposto de tal sistema é aquele que insiste em determinada ação mesmo que ela já se tenha demonstrado como inefetiva para seus propósitos (apesar de que continuar fazendo a mesma coisa na espera de resultados diferentes é, segundo creditado a Einstein, a definição de insanidade e não de burrice. hehehe).

Adaptação é algo ainda amplo. Por exemplo, os primeiros modelos computacionais de [autômatos celulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B3mato_celular), particularmente o famoso [Jogo da Vida](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jogo_da_vida) (quem tiver tempo sobrando, brinque com uma implementação dele em Javascript [neste link](http://pmav.eu/stuff/javascript-game-of-life-v3.1.1/)), buscavam construir sistemas capazes de se replicar. Se essa cópia de si mesmo não for exatamente igual à anterior, ela pode permitir/implementar a adaptação conforme necessidades especiais do ambiente de uma forma similar ao que ocorre na evolução. De fato, um paradigma parecido e chamado de [Algoritmos Genéticos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_gen%C3%A9tico) usa um princípio similar de adaptação de indivíduos para realizar buscas e/ou otimizações interessantes na resolução de problemas. Porém, dizer que esse tipo de abordagem é aprendizado de máquina é bastante discutível.

O aprendizado de máquina involve mais tradicionalmente a construção de sistemas capazes de extrair informações a partir de dados conhecidos e utilizar esse comportamento aprendido para a resolução de novos problemas. Por isso, muitas das técnicas utilizadas nessa área são também utilizadas em estatística, *business intelligence*, *data mining* (mineração de dados), *data science*, etc. De fato, há basicamente três abordagens principais no aprendizado de máquina:

**1. Aprendizado Preditivo ou Supervisionado**

Nesse tipo de abordagem, o algoritmo utiliza como entrada um conjunto prévio de dados coletados do mundo real e utilizado para "treinamento" antes do uso propriamente dito (dai a palavra "supervisionado"). Esse conjunto de dados tem uma parte (geralmente chamada de `x`) que contém as características de interesse do problema (imagine `x` como um vetor de valores quaisquer, de forma que o conjunto de dados contém várias linhas `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, etc, para cada *exemplo* coletado do mundo real), e outra parte (geralmente chamada de `y`) que contém o o valor que decorre das características em `x` ou a classe dos exemplos do mundo real (imagine que cada `y1`, `y2`, `y3` indica o que as respectivas linhas `x1`, `x2`, `x3` descrevem ou representam). Assim, a ideia é que o sistema "aprenda" o mapeamento entre `x` e `y` a partir dos dados de treinamento, para que posteriormente seja capaz de "prever" o valor de `y` para um novo `x`, isto é, o valor de uma função ou a classe a qual um novo exemplo (um novo vetor com todas as características medidas) pertence.

O exemplo de "algoritmo" mais comum nesse tipo de abordagem é a [Regressão Linear](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regress%C3%A3o_linear). Com esse método, é possível estimar uma função linear (uma equação da forma `y = ax + b`) que descreva o comportamento de um conjunto de dados (um mapeamento `x -> y`) segundo uma correlação linear. Tendo-se "aprendido" essa função, é possível estimar o valor de `y` para um novo `x` qualquer apenas utilizando-a com os novos parâmetros.

Outros algoritmos podem, ao invés de tentar estimar um valor numérico, predizer um valor enumerativo, que "classifica" um vetor `x` com as medidas de algo de interesse. Por exemplo, poder-se-ia construir um sistema capaz de identificar em imagens de laranjas as opções "podre" e "boa", ou identificar objetos móveis em um vídeo entre as opções "carro", "moto" e "caminhão". Para uma explicação mais detalhada dessa abordagem, e também alguns outros exemplos concretos, por favor leia [esta minha outra resposta aqui no SOPt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40149/73).

Os perceptrons, mencionados [pelo colega @Gomiero em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113405/73), e as redes neurais fazem essencialmente esse mesmo mapeamento (a saída de um neurônio pode indicar um valor, se usado para regressão, ou uma classe, se usado para classificação), e por isso são geralmente considerados métodos de aprendizado supervisionados (apesar de que as redes neurais podem também ser usadas para extrair padrões interessantes de dados, no sentido do próximo tipo de aprendizado). Mas há outros métodos que convém estudar. Como, por exemplo, as [árvores de decisão indutivas](http://www-usr.inf.ufsm.br/~pozzer/disciplinas/pj3d_decisionTrees.pdf), em que os dados de treinamento são utilizados para construir uma árvore de verificações que decide a classe de um vetor. Uma árvore de decisão nada mais é do que uma sequência de if's encadeados que verificam cada um dos atributos do dado (os valores do vetor `x`) para decidir qual é a resposta (`y`). Há algoritmos que permitem construir a árvore a partir de dados de treinamento, como o [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm), que utiliza a entropia nos dados para decidir quais atributos verificar antes dos demais (por oferecer *ganho* mais imediato a cada decisão).

**2. Aprendizado Descritivo ou Não-Supervisionado**

Nessa abordagem o algoritmo *não recebe* um conjunto de dados prévio para aprender um "mapeamento". A ideia é que o sistema seja capaz, por si só (dai a expressão "não-supervisionado"), de extrair padrões interessantes dos dados. Enquanto que na abordagem anterior o sistema é alimentado com pares de dados (de entrada e exemplos de saída) na fase de treinamento, nesta abordagem o sistema é apenas alimentado com os dados de entrada - a saída é diretamente deduzida.

Um exemplo bacana e simples de algoritmo muito utilizado na abordagem não-supervisionada é o [K-Médias (ou K-Means)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means). O "k" advém do número de classes desejado (isso é o mínimo que o projetista deve saber do problema). O algoritmo funciona assim:

- Primeiro, se escolhe aleatoriamente k vetores para os prováveis centros dos grupos.
- Então, as distâncias entre os demais vetores e esses centros são calculadas. Os vetores mais próximos dos centros temporários são "agrupados" a eles.
- Para cada grupo se calcula o "centro geométrico" do grupo (que é basicamente o valor médio de todos os dados no grupo - dai o restante do nome do algoritmo), e assim o centro do grupo é alterado para esse centro geométrico obtido.
- Os passos anteriores são repetidos até que o sistema atinja a convergência (isto é, os centros dos grupos não mais se alterem).

Uma ilustração visual do algoritmo, para um problema com k=2 (isto é, duas "classes" nos dados), é a seguinte (a imagem a seguir é um gif animado - cada quadro tem 4 segundos de duração):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seu uso é bem amplo. Por exemplo, no processamento de imagens, pode-se muitas vezes fazer a segmentação (extração) de elementos de interesse utilizando esse algoritmo. Os "pontos" de dados são os valores dos pixels (intensidade luminosa em uma das bandas RGB ou, mais comumente, em tons de cinza), e o número de classes é dado pelo projetista, que conhece quantos "elementos" se encontram na imagem. O exemplo concreto a seguir foi extraido do meu mestrado: em uma imagem microscópia capturada de uma placa de alumínio submetida a [jateamento com granalhas de aço](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granalha_de_a%C3%A7o) (imagem da esquerda), eu precisava separar as crateras (impactos das esferas/granalhas) do resto da imagem (para fazer uma medição importante no processo). Sabendo que a imagem contém essencialmente três elementos (a placa, as estrias e as crateras), eu usei o K-médias com k=3 pra agrupar os pixels nesses três grupos (imagem do meio) e depois escolhi o grupo de valor médio mais escuro jogando o resto fora (fazendo se tornar branco), pra gerar uma imagem (imagem da direita) apta a continuar sendo tratada por outros algoritmos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro exemplo de uso desse algoritmo é em jogos. Tendo-se uma base de dados coletada com informações do desempenho de jogadores em um jogo ao longo de um intervalo qualquer de tempo, pode-se processar os dados usando o K-Médias pra "automaticamente" inferir três agrupamentos (novamente, k=3). Como os dados tratam de desempenho, os grupos podem ser imaginados como sendo as caracterizações de novato, intermediário e especialista, por exemplo. Tendo-se esses grupos bem definidos (pelo vetor central de cada grupo), um novo jogador pode ser automaticamente classificado como pertencente a um desses grupos com base na distância aos centros (ele essencialmente pertence ao grupo que está mais próximo).

Há outros algoritmos que convém estudar, como por exemplo o [K-NN (k-vizinhos mais próximos)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm).

**3. Aprendizado por Reforço**

Nessa abordagem o sistema requalifica suas regras de avaliação com base em *feedbacks* observados do mundo. Diferentemente das abordagens anteriores, em que uma massa de dados é utilizada para construir um modelo de predição ou inferir um padrão interessante, nesse caso o sistema é construido essencialmente como uma máquina de estados estocástica (de transição não determinística), em que os nós são estados do mundo e as transições são ações que podem ser executadas levando de um estado a outro. As transições têm "recompensas" associadas, que podem ser ajustadas conforme os estados efetivamente alcançados de forma não-determinística são comparados aos estados esperados.

Eu admitidamente tenho pouquíssima (quase nenhuma, na verdade) experiência com essa abordagem, então a minha explicação é bem simplista. De todas as formas, todo o que eu expliquei até aqui definitivamente não cobre o que se pode estudar em aprendizagem de máquina. Por exemplo, há muitas abordagens que são inerentemente probabilísticas, como os [filtros de partículas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter), e que podem ser entendidas como aprendizagem por reforço no sentido de que o estado atual é constantemente refinado com base no ajuste das probabilidades.

Comment: Obrigado pela grande (literalmente) resposta. Vou ter que tirar um tempo especial para ler calmamente ;)

Comment: Opa. Por nada. Desculpe se ficou grande demais.

Comment: Ironia das inteligências artificias: Coloquei seu texto no google tradutor, para ela ler para mim.

Comment: E funcionou, né? :)

Comment: +1 para a opção de tradução como "Aprendizagem Computacional". "Aprendizado de Máquina", pelo menos para mim, é muito literal e estranho.

Comment: +1 pela excelente resposta.

Answer (score 8):

> O que seria o Machine Learning?

Conforme a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprendizado_de_m%C3%A1quina), são algoritmos e técnicas que permitem ao computador aprender, isto é, que permitem ao computador aperfeiçoar seu desempenho em alguma tarefa.

> Ele está relacionado à (ou é uma forma de) Inteligência Artificial?

Sim, está. É uma sub-área (ou sub-campo) da inteligência artificial.

> Que exemplo mais simples podemos citar a respeito desse assunto?

Acredito que o exemplo mais simples, é o funcionamento de um [perceptron](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron), ou classificador binário (neurônio artificial):

```
X1 ----- P1 -------          +----------------------------+
                    \        !  const threshold = 0.5;    !
X2 ----- P2 -----    \       !                            !
                  \   \      !  soma = ∑ (Xi*Pi)          !
                    ---O-----+  se (soma > threshold)     +-------> saída
                  /   /      !    saída = 1;              !
X3 ----- P3 -----    /       !  else                      !
                    /        !     saída = 0;             !
X4 ----- P4 -------          +----------------------------+
```

O perceptron, "aprende" através de **treino** da seguinte forma (explicação bem simplificada):

#### Fase 1 *feedforward*:

- Os sinais X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub> ... X<sub>n</sub> são sinais de entrada.
- Esses sinais, são multiplicados pelos pesos (P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>, .... P<sub>n</sub>)
- Calcula-se a somatória de X<sub>i</sub>*P<sub>i</sub> e compara-se esse valor com um *threshold* ou *bias* (limite)
- Se for maior ou igual a saída é `1`
- Se for menor, a saída é `0`

#### Fase 2 *backpropagation* (aqui é onde ocorre o aprendizado):

- Calcula-se o "**erro**": a diferença entre a saída esperada e a saída do perceptron (SE - SP)
- Calcula-se a "**correção**": multiplica-se o erro por uma **taxa de aprendizado** (uma constante definida previamente, ex: 0.01)
- Soma-se a "**correção**" calculada com o peso inicial (ex: `P1 = P1 + "correção"`; `P2 = P2 + "correção"`, `...`)
- Atualiza-se todos os pesos e volta para a **Fase 1** até que os erros sejam zero (ou pequenos o suficiente para determinar que a rede "aprendeu")

Após executar esse processo por um determinado número (bem grande) de vezes, caso haja conversão dos pesos (o erro tende a zero), é porque a o perceptron "aprendeu".

[Veja funcionando aqui](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w_qOWUWC5RudReZxKqfQzB0iCSQlvpvXC-oCylwOVcU)



Nessa planilha de exemplo, o perceptron aprende o funcionamento de uma porta lógica **"OU"** (*OR*).

O aprendizado ocorre na quinta iteração do treino, quando ele "entende" qual deve ser a saída.

O valores (pesos e taxa de aprendizado) foram ajustados para que o aprendizado ocorra mais devagar, para facilitar o entendimento do algoritmo.

Como é um exemplo bem simples, se a taxa de aprendizado tiver um valor maior, o perceptron já "aprende" na segunda interação.

Para conhecer mais sobre o assunto, recomendo os livros e links indicados na área "References" da Wikipedia em inglês:

[Wikipedia - Machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning)

Outros exemplos de algoritmos de aprendizado de máquina (em inglês):

[Naive Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)

[Random forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest)

[Support vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)

Answer (score 1):

Machine Learning ou Aprendizado de Máquina é um método de análise de dados que automatiza o desenvolvimento de modelos analíticos. Usando algoritmos que aprendem interativamente a partir de dados, o aprendizado de máquinas permite que os computadores encontrem insights ocultos sem serem explicitamente programados para procurar algo específico.

Answer (score 1):

O aprendizado de máquina é uma das subáreas mais relevantes da Inteligência Artificial (IA) que surgiu da ideia de criar programas que aprendam um determinado comportamento ou um determinado padrão automaticamente, a partir de exemplos ou observações. Você pode ler mais sobre Machine Learning e alguns conceitos no post "[Machine Learning e Azure](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/19/machine-learning-e-azure/)".

Agora, para ter uma ideia melhor sobre como funciona e ter um exemplo fácil de ser compreendido, sugiro ler o post "[Criando um modelo preditivo no Azure Machine Learning](http://talkitbr.com/2016/01/12/criando-um-modelo-preditivo-no-azure-machine-learning/)"

Esses dois posts vão te dar uma boa noção sobre esse assunto!

Answer (score 0):

> A aprendizagem automática ou aprendizado de máquina (em inglês: "machine learning") é um sub-campo da inteligência artificial dedicado ao desenvolvimento de algoritmos e técnicas que permitam ao computador aprender, isto é, que permitam ao computador aperfeiçoar seu desempenho em alguma tarefa. Enquanto que na inteligência artificial existem dois tipos de raciocínio - o indutivo, que extrai regras e padrões de grandes conjuntos de dados, e o dedutivo - o aprendizado de máquina só se preocupa com o indutivo.
>
> Algumas partes da aprendizagem automática estão intimamente ligadas à mineração de dados e estatística. Sua pesquisa foca nas propriedades dos métodos estatísticos, assim como sua complexidade computacional.
>
> Sua aplicação prática inclui:
>
> 1. Reconhecimento de padrões de compra ou consumo
> 2. o processamento de linguagem natural
> 3. motores de busca, diagnósticos médicos
> 4. bioinformática
> 5. reconhecimento de fala
> 6. reconhecimento de escrita
> 7. visão computacional
> 8. locomoção de robôs.

Fonte: [Wikpédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprendizado_de_m%C3%A1quina)