# Algoritmo de distribuição de pixels

Tags: c++, imagem, jogos, processamento-de-imagens

Bom, ultimamente tenho pensado em algoritmos para criar mapas/imagens randômicas e me veio uma dúvida que vou postar aqui para vocês elucidarem.

Suponham que eu tenha pixels verdes e amarelos. Não estou trabalhando com matriz, mas sim um vetor unidimensional por conta do projeto.

Alguém poderia me citar um esboço de algoritmo ou de onde começar para distribuir os pixels agrupadamente a cada vez que eu rode o programa, porém, que não seja sempre o mesmo resultado, que crie formas com esses pixels verdes e amarelos?

Comment: Em qual linguagem você está programando? O que você quer dizer com agrupados? Uma sequência randômica não é o suficiente?

Comment: Estou fazendo em c++. A ideia é gerar um mapa com terra/areia, ou seja, seria interessante ter zonas onde os pixels semelhantes ficassem agrupados.

Comment: Adicionei a tag [tag:jogos] só porque a pergunta se aplica à geração automatizada de conteúdo (mapas, no caso).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quer algo como o que está abaixo? Clique no botão azul para executar.

```js
function agrupar(antes) {
    var depois = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < antes.length; i++) {
        var a = i === 0 ? "A" : antes.charAt(i - 1);
        var b = antes.charAt(i);
        var c = i === antes.length - 1 ? "A" : antes.charAt(i + 1);
        var m = (a === "V" ? 1 : 0) + (b === "V" ? 1 : 0) + (c === "V" ? 1 : 0);
        depois += m >= 2 ? "V" : "A";
    }
    return depois;
}

var cores = "VA";

var resultado = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    resultado += cores.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * cores.length));
}

$("#antes").html(resultado);
resultado = agrupar(resultado);
$("#depois1").html(resultado);
resultado = agrupar(resultado);
$("#depois2").html(resultado);
resultado = agrupar(resultado);
$("#depois3").html(resultado);
```

```css
#antes, #depois1, #depois2, #depois3 {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td>Original ranômico:</td><td id='antes'></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Agrupando 1:</td><td id='depois1'></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Agrupando 2:</td><td id='depois2'></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Agrupando 3:</td><td id='depois3'></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmm, vi agora que a pergunta foi editada especificando C++ como linguagem de programação. Vou deixar a minha resposta aqui caso o algoritmo interesse ao OP ou a terceiros.

Comment: Sim, é algo do tipo e já vai ajudar muito, pois acredito que o mais importante no caso é a lógica do que a sintaxe. No meu caso tenho outro problema, como é um mapa/imagem e estou tratando como vetor unidimencional, preciso arrumar um modo de equilibrar também as adjascencias no eixo y, pois esse teu algoritmo resolve no x.

Comment: @DJM_JM Se ele é unidimensional, então simplesmente não haveria eixo y, apenas eixo x. Assim sendo, não entendo o que você quis dizer. Poderia explicar melhor o que está tentando fazer? O que você quer dizer por tratar o mapa/imagem (que acredito ser bidimensional) como um vetor unidimensional? Quer dizer que você tem um vetorzão com `w*h` elementos onde cada bloquinho de `w` elementos é uma linha? Ou você quer dizer outra coisa? Edite a pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Comment: É um vetorzão unidimencional de 2500 que representa um mapa 50 x 50. É exatamente isso que tu disse, eu simulo os eixos x e y a partir desse "vetorzão".

Comment: @DJM_JM Nesse caso, na função `agrupar`, eu devo pegar o elemento e os seus 8 vizinhos próximos ao invés de o elemento e os seus 2 vizinhos. E ao invés de `m >= 2`, você usaria `m >= 4` ou `m >= 5`. A fórmula para acessar o elemento `x,y` no vetorzão é `vetor[y * largura + x]`. Outras possíveis variantes seria dar pesos diferentes aos vizinhos (por exemplo, os que estão diagonalmente adjacentes têm peso menor do que os lateralmente adjacentes) ou então pegar vizinhos que não estejam imediatamente adjacentes, mas também a 2 ou 3 pixels de distância.

Answer (score 7):

Como eu já havia comentado, há uma infinidade de sugestões que podem ser feitas. Mas infelizmente você não deu retorno a respeito do seu problema, então não tem como sugerir algo mais apropriado. Paciência.

A sua resposta atual (que você já aceitou, aliás) tem uma sugestão possível, que funciona bem. Mas, como você mesmo observou nos comentários, trabalhar com os dados como um único vetor unidimensional também tem as suas dificuldades. Por isso eu sugeri que você trabalhasse com a imagem no formato tradicional (isto é, bidimensional) e só então transformasse os dados para o formato unidimensional que você precisa (sabe-se lá o porquê, já que você não descreve). Essa abordagem te dará margem pra trabalhar com diversos algoritmos diferentes e, principalmente, de reutilizar código pronto que existe por aí.

Enfim, eis uma implementação simples da sugestão utilizando o algoritmo de crescimento de região que eu comentei anteriormente. A explicação está documentada no código.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include "image.h"

// ------------------------------
// Remova se não usar OpenCV
// ------------------------------
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
// ------------------------------

/**
 * Função de geração de um número inteiro aleatório entre um intervalo dado.
 * @param min Inteiro com o mímimo número esperado.
 * @param max Inteiro com o máximo número esperado.
 * @return Inteiro com o valor sorteado.
 */
int random(int min, int max)
{
    int n = max - min + 1;
    int remainder = RAND_MAX % n;
    int x;
    do
    {
        x = rand();
    } while(x >= RAND_MAX - remainder);
    return min + x % n;
}

/**
 * Gera um mapa de regiões aleatórias.
 * @param colors Vetor de Pixels com as cores possívels
 * para as regiões.
 * @param width Inteiro positivo com o largura da imagem gerada.
 * @param width Inteiro positivo com o altura da imagem gerada.
 * @param iterations Inteiro positivo com o número de interações para
 * o agrupamento de pixels sob a imagem inicialmente aleatória. O default
 * é 100 mil. Se esse valor for 0, nenhuma permutação é realizada e a imagem
 * do mapa resultante contém apenas ruído.
 * @param window Inteiro positivo com o tamanho da janela de comparação para
 * o agrupamento. Essa janela tem que ser um número cuja raíz quadrada resulta
 * em um inteiro ímpar (9, 25, 49, 81, etc) de valor mínimo 9.
 * @return Objeto Image com a imagem gerada.
 */
Image genMap(vector<Pixel> colors, uint width, uint height, uint iterations = 100000, uint window = 9)
{
    // Checa os parâmetros de entrada
    double windowRoot = std::sqrt(window);
    if(windowRoot < 3 || (windowRoot - int(windowRoot)) != 0 || int(windowRoot) % 2 == 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("tamanho de janela invalido");

    // Usa o horário atual como semente para o gerador de números aleatórios
    std::srand((uint)std::time(0));

    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // 1 - Cria o mapa totalmente em preto
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Image map(width, height);

    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // 2 - Sorteia aleatoriamente os pixels nas cores recebidas
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    for(uint x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for(uint y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            uint c = random(0, colors.size()-1);
            map.pixel(x, y) = colors[c];
        }
    }

    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // 3 - Agrupa os pixels aleatoriamente, para formar as regiões  
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    uint offset = int(std::ceil(windowRoot) / 2);
    for(uint i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        // Sorteia um pixel qualquer na imagem
        int xCenter = random(0, width-1);
        int yCenter = random(0, height-1);
        Pixel color = map.pixel(xCenter, yCenter);

        // Conta quantos são os pixels vizinhos que são iguais
        // ao pixel "central" sorteado
        int count = 0;
        for(uint x = xCenter - offset; x <= xCenter + offset; x++)
        {
            for(uint y = yCenter - offset; y <= yCenter + offset; y++)
            {
                // Desconsidera pixels fora da área da imagem
                if(x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height)
                    continue;

                // Incrementa se for a mesma cor
                if(map.pixel(x, y) == color)
                    count++;
            }
        }

        // Se mais da metade da janela é da mesma cor do pixel central,
        // transforma todos os vizinhos na cor do pixel central
        if(count > int(window / 2))
        {
            for(uint x = xCenter - offset; x <= xCenter + offset; x++)
            {
                for(uint y = yCenter - offset; y <= yCenter + offset; y++)
                {
                    // Desconsidera pixels fora da área da imagem
                    if(x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height)
                        continue;

                    // Define a cor
                    map.pixel(x, y) = color;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // Pronto! Só devolve a imagem gerada. :)
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    return map;
}

// ------------------------------
// Remova se não usar OpenCV
// ------------------------------
void showImage(char *title, Mat image)
{
    namedWindow(title, cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(title, image);
}
// ------------------------------

/**
 * Converte a imagem (bidimensional) para um longo vetor de
 * valores (unidimensional).
 * @return Vetor de com todos os valores dos pixels (na ordem
 * R, G, B) agrupados linha após linha.
 */
vector<uchar> imageToVector(const Image &image)
{
    vector<uchar> ret;
    for(uint y = 0; y < image.height(); y++)
    {
        for(uint x = 0; x < image.width(); x++)
        {
            Pixel p = image.pixel(x, y);
            ret.push_back(p.red);
            ret.push_back(p.green);
            ret.push_back(p.blue);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

/**
 * Converte um longo vetor de valores (unidimensional) para uma
 * imagem (bidimensional).
 * @param data Vetor com todos os valores dos pixels (na ordem
 * R, G, B) agrupados linha após linha.
 * @param width Inteiro positivo com a largura da imagem.
 * @param height Inteiro positivo com a altura da imagem.
 */
Image vectorToImage(vector<uchar> data, uint width, uint height)
{
    if(data.size() != (width * height * 3))
        throw std::invalid_argument("os dados e as dimensoes recebidos não são condizentes com uma imagem em 3 canais");

    Image ret(width, height);
    for(uint i = 0; i < data.size(); i += 3)
    {
        int x = (i / 3) % width;
        int y = (i / 3) / width;
        ret.pixel(x, y) = Pixel(data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2]);
    }

    return ret;
}

/**
 * Função principal.
 */
int main()
{
    Pixel amarelo(255, 255, 0);
    Pixel verde(0, 255, 0);

    Image t1 = genMap({ amarelo, verde }, 400, 300, 0);
    Image t2 = genMap({ amarelo, verde }, 400, 300, 100000);
    Image t3 = genMap({ amarelo, verde }, 400, 300, 100000, 25);
    Image t4 = genMap({ amarelo, verde }, 400, 300, 500000, 25);

    cout << "Teste 1: " << endl;
    cout << t1 << endl << endl;

    cout << "Teste 2: " << endl;
    cout << t2 << endl << endl;

    cout << "Teste 3: " << endl;
    cout << t3 << endl << endl;

    cout << "Teste 4: " << endl;
    cout << t4 << endl << endl;

    // ------------------------------
    // Remova se não usar OpenCV
    // ------------------------------
    showImage("Teste 1 - Aleatoria", t1.toMat());
    showImage("Teste 2 - Janela: 9 e Iteracoes: 100 mil", t2.toMat());
    showImage("Teste 3 - Janela: 25 e Iteracoes: 100 mil", t3.toMat());
    showImage("Teste 4 - Janela: 25 e Iteracoes: 500 mil", t4.toMat());
    waitKey(0);
    // ------------------------------

    cout << endl << "Teste de Conversao" << endl;
    Image t = genMap({ amarelo, verde }, 4, 10, 0);

    cout << "Imagem bidimensional original: " << endl;
    cout << t << endl << endl; 

    cout << "Convertida para vetor unidimensional: " << endl;
    vector<uchar> v = imageToVector(t);
    for(uint i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cout << int(v[i]) << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Convetida de volta para imagem bidimensional: " << endl;
    cout << vectorToImage(v, 4, 10) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ele gera a seguinte saída de texto:

```
Teste 1:
Largura: 400 Altura: 300
Pixels:
[(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
mais 290 linhas...


Teste 2:
Largura: 400 Altura: 300
Pixels:
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
mais 290 linhas...


Teste 3:
Largura: 400 Altura: 300
Pixels:
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
mais 290 linhas...


Teste 4:
Largura: 400 Altura: 300
Pixels:
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0), mais 390 colunas...]
mais 290 linhas...



Teste de Conversao
Imagem bidimensional original:
Largura: 4 Altura: 10
Pixels:
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0)]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0)]


Convertida para vetor unidimensional:
0 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 255 255 0 0 255 0

Convetida de volta para imagem bidimensional:
Largura: 4 Altura: 10
Pixels:
[(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,0)]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(255,255,0)]
[(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0)]
```

E gera também a seguinte saída gráfica (dependente do OpenCV - não utilize se não tiver instalado):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Rapidamente, como esse código funciona:

1. Ele cria uma imagem (um vetor bidimensional de pixels, com 3 canais já que vc fala de cores - poderia ser um canal só para imagens em tons de cinza) e define os pixels aleatoriamente conforme as cores dadas (imagem do teste 1).
2. Então, ele agrupa os pixels fazendo uma espécie de crescimento de região iterativo: sorteia um pixel e verifica as cores da vizinhança (segundo uma janela predefinida); se os vizinhos tiverem bastante da cor do pixel sorteado, ele altera **toda** a vizinhança para aquela cor, tornando-a então homogênea (isto é, um agrupamento).
3. Repete o passo 2 para uma nova interação.

Assim, deve ser possível perceber que o número de interações e o tamanho da janela influenciam no resultado. Porém, muitas interações fazem o processamento naturalmente demorar mais. É importante encontrar um balanceamento adequado para a sua necessidade.

Eu implementei duas classes auxiliares chamadas `Image` e `Pixel` para te permitir rodar esse código de forma genérica (sem o OpenCV, que eu só uso pra exibir as imagens porque elas são bacanas!). Mas essa implementação é bem tosca e simples. Se você puder, use diretamente outra estrutura (tal qual o `Mat` do OpenCV, que já implementa uma série de algoritmos que você pude usar pra manipular e gerar estruturas mais interessantes).

Se você tem os dados originalmente em um vetor unidimensional, converta-os para uma estrutura bidimensional, use esse algoritmo e depois converta de volta para unidimensional.

> Finalmente, duas informações adicionais:
>
> 1. Se a sua necessidade envolve a geração de conteúdo (um terreno para um jogo, talvez?), há muitas outras abordagens que podem ser úteis.
>      Nesse caso, sugiro também dar uma olhada nesta [minha outra resposta
>      sobre Geração Procedural de Conteúdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/128060/73).
> 2. Caso a necessidade real por trás da ideia do vetor unidimensional seja algo relacionado à serialização da imagem, há formas melhores de
>      fazer isso. Em muitos casos nativa mesmo da implementação da
>      biblioteca que você for utilizar. No OpenCV, por exemplo, vc tem
>      acesso direto ao atributo `data` da classe `Mat` se precisar, além do
>      que existem [várias sugestões por aí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170745/serializing-opencv-mat-vec3f) de como fazer.

O código completo (incluindo as classes auxiliares `Image` e `Pixel`) está [no Github](https://github.com/luigivieira/SimpleMapCreator).

> **EDIT**: Eu também havia comentado outras possibilidades, entre elas o
>   uso de [Autômatos Celulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B3mato_celular). Pra ver um exemplo funcional bem
>   bacana que pode ser útil na geração de mapas, eu sugiro brincar [com
>   essa implementação em JavaScript](http://pmav.eu/stuff/javascript-game-of-life-v3.1.1/) do famoso autômato celular
>   chamado de [Jogo da Vida](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jogo_da_vida).