# Machine Learning usando R e excel

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Olá 
Tenho alguns dados que faço tabulação no excel mensalmente, o que é muito repetitivo. Gostaria de saber se ha alguma forma de usar machine Learning no R para ensinar um algoritmo, baseado nos dados que eu ja tenho, preencher o novos dados que chegam.
Basicamente eu recebo os dados em colunas com ID, origem, descrição, quantidades, valores e etc. Sobre esse dados eu tabulo as infos detalhadas que preciso, como por exemplo a marca (ex: olho a coluna descrição e verifico qual é a marca) e assim sucessivamente vou colocando em outras colunas na mesma planilha os dados tabulados da forma desejada.
Esse processo é  logo e repetitivo demais e portanto toma muito tempo. Lendo sobre Machine Learning vi que na linguagem R posso treinar um algoritmo para analisar meus dados tabulados anteriormente e baseado nisso o algoritmo poderia me fornecer qual seriam as marcas, produtores, origens e etc.

Minha pergunta é, como posso aplicar isso ao meu trabalho usando R para agilizar o processo?

Ps. Se ainda não ficou bem claro me perdoem pois é realmente difícil descrever.

Comment: **Sim, há várias formas possíveis.** Essa "resposta" te ajudou? Não né? :) Pois é... ela tá igual à sua pergunta: ampla e genérica. Edite a questão para melhorá-la, procurando descrever o seu problema com exemplos práticos. Caso contrário, ninguém vai conseguir te ajudar. Também foque no problema, postando qualquer código R que você já tenha. Se a sua dúvida for muito do tipo "qual é a melhor técnica de ML", ela pode não fazer parte do escopo desse site (e aí, seria melhor postar no [Cross-Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)). Ah, e se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask].

Comment: Olá, tentei melhorar!! Desculpe.

Comment: Ainda está ampla e agora ficou menos clara. Vc diz que preenche colunas com base em outras colunas olhando a marca (por exemplo), mas isso não tem nada de aprendizado, apenas mera observação. Qualquer algoritmo de extração de dados faz isso. Se o trabalho é repetitivo, você precisa de automação e não de aprendizagem de máquina. Parece que você precisa é de [VBA](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications), não de R.

Comment: Sugiro ler outras perguntas por aqui. Comece pela tag [tag:vba], por exemplo. Vai te dar uma visão do que você pode fazer. Se ainda assim você achar que precisa mesmo de ML, leia as perguntas na tag [tag:aprendizagem-de-máquina]. Particularmente [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113343/qual-%c3%a9-a-defini%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-aprendizado-de-m%c3%a1quina-machine-learning) pode ser útil para uma visão geral.

Comment: P.S.: Machine Learning lhe vai ser útil se você desejar **prever** uma classe (a marca de um produto, por exemplo) a partir de algum conjunto de dados **que se correlacione com a classe**. Observe que isso não vai ser necessariamente verdade para quaisquer dados. Por exemplo: embora talvez seja possível prever a marca de um produto com base em reviews de usuários num site ou no número de vendas (porque talvez haja relação decorrente das diferenças em qualidade), é improvável que se possa prever a marca com base em peso (já que o mesmo produto em marcas diferentes pode ter o mesmo peso).

Comment: O campo que eu uso para extrair as infos é o campo descrição, que baseado em um histórico que eu tenho, consigo saber que aquela descricao é de tal marca.

Comment: Se você for mesmo usar ML, vai ter muita coisa que precisará aprender antes de ser capaz de ter uma solução. Como os dados relevantes não são numéricos, mas sim texto, precisa ter um passo intermediário de extração de características. Vc vai ter uma ideia disso [neste link](http://www.maxwell.vrac.puc-rio.br/9947/9947_4.PDF). Assim, se for possível fazer uma automatização mais simples com VBA, eu acho que vc devia ir por esse caminho, ok? Boa sorte.