# Deep, Machine Learning e IA. Qual suas diferenças?

Tags: terminologia, inteligência-artificial, machine-learning

A respeito de Deep Learning, Machine Learning e Artificial Intelligence, quais são suas principais diferenças?

- Quais são seus princípios?
- São todos que conseguem aprender e resolver problemas de natureza própria?
- Como se distingue uma da outra?

Comment: Não entendi exatamente o que você quis dizer com "resolver problemas de natureza própria"

Comment: @ArthurFerraz quis dizer sobre a máquina identificar problemas e resolver eles sem uma programação totalmente explícita ali.

Comment: As técnicas de ML podem resolver problemas sem serem explicitamente programadas para tal. Só não entendi exatamente o que seria identificar problemas.

Comment: @ArthurFerraz máquinas que identificam situações que elas mesmas podem lidar.

Comment: DL é um modelo de ML específico, e ML é feito como uma das técnicas possíveis para se aumentar a função de fitness de um agente inteligente, voltado para obter uma boa IA fraca

Comment: Se está em código é Machine Learning, se está em PowerPoint é Inteligência Artificial :P :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A diferença básica entre as áreas citadas está na granularidade. Deep Learning é uma subárea de Machine Learning, que por sua vez é uma subárea Inteligência Artificial.

Ou seja, toda técnica de Deep Learning também é de Machine Learning e, por conseguinte, de Inteligência Artificial. Já nem todo algoritmo de IA é de ML, e nem todo algoritmo de ML é de Deep Learning.

### Inteligência Artificial

Definir Inteligência Artificial é bastante complicado pelo fato de que o termo inteligência não é bem definido. Mas resumidamente seria a área que estuda algoritmos que buscam imitar o comportamento inteligente humano. Então qualquer algoritmo que pretenda ser inteligente em algum aspecto, seria considerado de Inteligência Artificial.

Posso citar algoritmos de otimização, como 'Encontrar a melhor rota possível passando por N pontos', como um problema de IA que é resolvido sem utilizar Machine Learning.

### Machine Learning

A confusão entre IA e Machine Learning (ML) hoje em dia é bastante comum porque boa parte dos sucessos e avanços de IA estão ligados a técnicas de ML, entretanto essa área é corresponde apenas a uma parte dos algoritmos.

ML é comumente definido como conjunto de algoritmos de IA que são **capazes de realizar um procedimento sem serem explicitamente programados para isso.**

Podemos citar como técnicas de ML Árvores de Decisão, Redes Bayesianas e até mesmo o famigerado Page Rank (algoritmo de rankeamento do Google). Entretanto, todas essas citadas **não** são técnicas de Deep Learning (DL).

### Deep Learning

Umas das técnicas mais bem sucedidas de ML tem sido as Redes Neurais. Devido ao aumento da capacidade de processamento foi possível construir redes cada vez mais profundas, dando origem ao termo Deep Learning.

Deep Learning então seria a área dentro de Machine Learning que estuda especificamente Redes Neurais profundas.

As técnicas mais populares da DL que posso citar são as Redes Neurais Convolucionais (muito úteis para resolver problemas com imagens) e LSTM (úteis para resolver problemas em que existe dependência de ordem, como geração de texto).

[image]

Referência: https://propus.science/diferenciacoes-entre-inteligencia-artificial-machine-learning-e-deep-learning/)

Essa Thread tem uma ótima explicação sobre o tema: [Qual é a definição de Aprendizado de Máquina (Machine Learning)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113343/qual-%C3%A9-a-defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-aprendizado-de-m%C3%A1quina-machine-learning?rq=1)

Qualquer dúvida pode perguntar que enriqueço a resposta.

Comment: Boa a clareza e explicação dos três itens, mas não compreendi relação. Por mais que na explicação, tenha sido esclarecido onde cada uma atua na outra, não torna claro o que difere uma da outra, nem seus princípios.

Comment: Dei uma editada na resposta para ver se fica mais claro. Mas de forma geral o importante é entender que Deep Learning é uma subárea de Machine Learning que, por sua vez, é uma subárea de Inteligência Artificial.