# O que é a Singularidade Tecnológica?

Tags: terminologia, ciência-da-computação, inteligência-artificial

Sempre que leio alguma [notícia](http://gizmodo.uol.com.br/avanco-inteligencia-artificial-singularidade/) relacionada a inteligência artificial me surgi a palavra **singularidade**, e junto com ela vem a tal da Singularidade Tecnologia. Eu já pesquisei a respeito do termo, entretanto, ele ainda esta confuso em minha mente, não consigo entender de forma clara o que é a singularidade relacionada a inteligência artificial e nem se este termo foi criado por alguém do campo da computação.

Portanto, eu gostaria de ter esta minha dúvida sanada.

## Dúvida

- O que seria a Singularidade Tecnológica?

Comment: Nós somos os Borg. Você será assimilado. Resistir é inútil.

Comment: Johnny Depp fez um filme sobre isso, em que _ele_ era a singularidade

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Você já viu os filmes da série *Exterminador do Futuro*?

Comment: @VictorStafusa minha infância foi na década de 90, Exterminador do Futuro 2 era o filme que meus pais botavam para me acalmar xD

Comment: Eu citei o do Johnny Depp porque ele é recente e trata de coisas muito interessantes. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence o filme

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado excelente sua citação desse filme, esse filme é uma adaptação do livro que melhor trata esse tema "A era das máquinas espirituais" do Kurzweil .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Como conceito geral (singularidade)

Em engenharia, singularidade é quando um mecanismo atinge um estado em que não dá mais para prever o que acontecerá em seguida.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_singularity

Em matemática, singularidade é o ponto onde um determinado conjunto passa a se comportar de forma anormal, ou não é definido.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)

### Aplicado em IA (geralmente grafado "A Singularidade")

O termo foi cunhado por [John von Neumann](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann) nos meados de 1950.

É basicamente o momento em que a [inteligência da máquina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86869/70) ultrapassa a do humano, a ponto de perdermos o controle e a previsibilidade da situação. Neste ponto, esta máquina pode construir máquinas mais inteligentes ainda, e sabe-se lá o que é que elas vão decidir por conta própria.

Da Wikipedia:

> *"reação desenfreada" de um agente inteligente atualizável com capacidade de auto-aperfeiçoamento (como um computador que executa inteligência artificial baseada em software) geraria cada vez mais rapidamente, indivíduos dotados de uma super inteligência poderosa que, qualitativamente, ultrapassaria toda a inteligência humana.*
>
> https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularidade_tecnol%C3%B3gica

Answer (score 4):

Trocando em miúdos o que disse o [Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) brilhantemente em sua resposta, o termo se refere àquele momento ou *ponto único* (de *singular*, por isso o termo Singularidade) na história em que a tecnologia (focada em AI - inteligência artificial) se tornaria tão avançada ao ponto de que as máquinas passariam a ter uma auto-capacidade de processamento e previsibilidade infinita, de modo que elas deixariam de ser apenas escravas baseadas em instruções e passariam a tomar decisões mais amplas e ilimitadas, de forma superior e incompreensível à capacidade humana.

No cinema tal situação foi abordada de forma fictícia em filmes como *Matrix* (1999), *O Exterminador do Futuro* (1984), A.I - Inteligência Artificial (2001), entre outros.

Alguns renomados cientistas já previram tal evento décadas atrás. Para citar alguns, como o conhecido matemático Alan Turing:

> Em seu artigo de 1951 intitulado *Intelligent Machinery: A Heretical
>   Theory*, Alan Turing escreveu sobre máquinas que eventualmente
>   superarão a inteligência humana:
>
> "Uma vez que o método de pensamento da máquina tenha começado, não
>   demorará muito para ultrapassar nossos fracos poderes. ... Em algum
>   momento, devemos esperar que as máquinas assumam o controle, da
>   maneira que é mencionada no Erewhon de Samuel Butler ".

Outro famoso cientista americano Vernor Vinge, introduziu o termo *singularidade tecnológica* na edição de janeiro de 1983 da revista Omni de forma especificamente ligada à criação de máquinas inteligentes:

> "Em breve criaremos inteligências maiores que as nossas. Quando isso
>   acontecer, a história humana atingirá uma espécie de singularidade,
>   uma transição intelectual tão impenetrável como o espaço-tempo atado
>   no centro de um buraco negro, e o mundo passará muito além do nosso
>   entendimento. Essa singularidade, acredito, já assombra vários
>   escritores de ficção científica. Isso torna impossível a extrapolação
>   realista para um futuro interestelar. Para escrever uma história de
>   mais de um século, é preciso uma guerra nuclear entre ... para que o
>   mundo permaneça inteligível".

Mais tarde, desenvolveu mais o conceito em seu ensaio *The Coming Technological Singularity* (1993):

> "Dentro de trinta anos, teremos os meios tecnológicos para criar
>   inteligência sobre-humana. Pouco depois, a era humana será encerrada.
>   [...] penso que é justo chamar esse evento de uma singularidade. É um
>   ponto em que nossos modelos devem ser descartados e uma nova realidade
>   é válida. À medida que nos aproximamos cada vez mais deste ponto, será
>   mais vasto e mais vasto sobre os assuntos humanos até que a noção se
>   torne um lugar comum. No entanto, quando finalmente acontece, ainda
>   pode ser uma grande surpresa e um maior desconhecido".

É importante enfatizar que, para Vinge, a singularidade pode ocorrer de quatro maneiras:

1. O desenvolvimento de computadores que estão "acordados" e
   superhumanamente inteligentes.
2. As grandes redes de computadores (e seus usuários associados) podem
   "acordar" como uma entidade super-humanamente inteligente.
3. As interfaces computador / humano podem tornar-se tão íntimas que os
   usuários podem razoavelmente ser considerados super-humanamente
   inteligentes.
4. A ciência biológica pode encontrar maneiras de melhorar o intelecto
   humano natural.

Como o assunto é amplo e interessante, para não ficar muito extenso, termino a resposta por aqui. Espero que tenha ajudado um pouco mais na compreensão.

Usei como **fonte de pesquisa** o site abaixo, que ainda provê 17 definições do termo relacionando seus respectivos cientistas:

https://www.singularityweblog.com/17-definitions-of-the-technological-singularity/