# Podemos criar Inteligência Artificial em qualquer linguagem?

Tags: característica-linguagem, inteligência-artificial

Sobre Inteligência Artificial, **gostaria de saber superficialmente**, pensando em iniciar o conhecimento nessa área:

- Pode ser criada em **qualquer linguagem**?
- Basicamente, qual seria **o conceito que define que um código é IA**?
- Existe um **padrão**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Pode ser criada em qualquer linguagem?

Linguagem de programação? Sim, pode. Se não for, não pode.

IA no fundo é algoritmo, com muita base em estatística e grande volume de dados e de uma forma ou outra todas podem fazê-lo. A qualidade e a facilidade depende muito. Mas muitas que não são boas estão se virando bem usando APIs externas.

Tem linguagens de programação que são melhores, por exemplo PROLOG foi criada para isto. Até LISP, praticamente a primeira linguagem de programação, foi criada para atender a esta demanda. Mas o mercado quer usar o que já conhece e prefere pagar por APIs em nuvem de grandes fornecedores. Tem lá suas vantagens.

Alguns poderão dizer que isso não é programar IA, é só consumir. E pode ser correto mesmo. Outros dizem que essa IA de caixinha não existe e que se você não colocar alguma inteligência no seu código não será IA, mesmo que parte seja "comprado" de alguma lugar.

> Basicamente, qual seria o conceito que define que um código é IA?

Acredito que isto está respondido em [O que é inteligência artificial?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86869/101).

> Existe um padrão específico?

Não sei bem o que isso quer dizer, mas acho que não.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Linguagem de programação? Sim, pode. Se não for, não pode." Só fiquei com uma certa dúvida nisso por conta da velha e conhecida questão: Nesse contexto, o PHP entraria no conceito "Linguagem de programação" ou ainda se manteria fora?

Comment: Algum motivo para pensar assim?

Comment: Então, sempre que passa perto disso fica um pouco no ar "Linguagem compilada, interpretada", aí entra o contexto no meio...  Mas independente de compilada ou interpretada, entendo as 2 como sendo linguagem de programação. Acertei!? 

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101

Comment: Você pode usar qualquer uma, pode ser em PHP, Haskell ou que seja em Python. Porém, é muito complexo montar esses modelos matemáticos do zero de forma eficiente e que aproveito recursos como paralelismo, é por motivos de performance, que um Tensorflow da vida funciona com C++ ou CUDA e é disponibilizado como Framework pra outras Langs. Diria que hoje em dia o Python é mais usado para manipular essas freamworks que não são construídas em Python.

Answer (score 4):

1- Se você tem a premissa que uma inteligência artificial é um algoritmo que irá tomar decisões para você, acho que pode ser programada em qualquer linguagem. No fundo acho que trabalhar com IA é mais entender os algoritimos que existem, como por exemplo o Minimax e a distância de Manhatan. Se você irá programar em python ou c, isso é da aplicação que você irá fazer.

2- Acho que a definição de um código de IA é um pouco complicada porque você deve responder o que é considerado uma IA. Na minha comcepção é algoritmo que irá tomar decisões sozinhas a partir de um ambiente que você dá como entrada, aí na teoria existem vários tipos de IA. Se você faz uma ia para jogar jogo da velha com um monte de 'if' e 'else' para mim já é um codigo de IA.

3- Como eu disse, podem existir IA simples que joga jogo da velha, até uma IA que irá cruzar o país inteiro em um carro autonomo. Então não acho que existe um padrão, apenas complexidades diferentes.