# Inteligência Artificial para Jogos no Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, inteligência-artificial, machine-learning

estou criando um jogo na unity, e estou querendo fazer alguns bosses, só que pra isso preciso estudar inteligência artificial, e não faço a minima ideia de por onde começar, procurei por livros mas são muito escassos, e os que achei ou não são em C#(unica linguagem que eu sei além de Kotlin) ou então(mais comum) não tem nenhuma relação com Jogos, onde eu posso conseguir fontes de Estudo? O Estilo de Boss que eu quero projetar é no Estilo do Jogo Hollow Knight, se vocês puderem dar uma olhada no primeiro boss, o "False Knight" eu agradeceria muito! Me recomendem locais pra estudar isso! Tenho muita sede de conhecimento e aprendo rápido, só preciso da fonte ou das fontes corretas.

Comment: Tem certeza que precisa de uma inteligência artificial, e não de uma inteligência 'simples', com padrões pré-definidos e que não mudam, como 98% dos jogos do mundo?

Comment: recomendo ver os seguintes sites antes de tomar essa decisão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86869/o-que-%c3%a9-intelig%c3%aancia-artificial?rq=1, https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inteligência_artificial, https://www.tecmundo.com.br/intel/1039-o-que-e-inteligencia-artificial-.htm, https://canaltech.com.br/inteligencia-artificial/entenda-a-importancia-da-inteligencia-artificial-100442/

Answer (score 6):

O chefe "False Knight" em Hollow Night não usa uma IA avançada como machine learning ou deep learning, que são IAs de aprendizado. 
Você consegue decorar os padrões dos chefes com o tempo em Hollow Night, como quando ele vai atacar desta maneira ou pular ou bater a clava dos dois lados do chão, e seu cerébro memoriza esses padrões com o tempo.
Então o False Knight usa uma IA simples chamada de : Máquina de estados finitos. É um bom começo para começar a estudar.

O que isso significa? Que ele tem seus ataques predefinidos por exemplo:

1. Ataque de pulo e bater clava no rumo do personagem.
2. Ataque de clava simples.
3. Ataque de clava com poder do chao.
4. Ataque de clava no centro dos dois lados.

Basicamente a máquina de estados finitos vão dizer as condições em que ele realizará cada ataque. Exemplo de condições:

1. Player está perto.
2. Playes está longe.
3. Player está no ar.

Uma representação em C# poderia ser:

```
public enum BossStateIA
{
     ExecutandoAcao,
     RequerAcao
}

public enum BossAcao
{
     Nenhuma,
     AtaqueSimples,
     AtaquePulo,
     AtaqueEspecial
}

public class Boss
{
     private BossStateIA State;
     private Acao AcaoAtual;

     private Acao IA()
     {
         Acao acao;

         //Define a próxima ação a ser feita em uma máquina de estados
         //finitas, simplesmente use ifs, and e or. Se o personagem 
         //está perto, longe, pouca vida ets.

         return acao;
     }

     public void Update()
     {
         if (State == BossStateIA.RequerAcao)
         {
             AcaoAtual = IA();
             State = BossStateIA.ExecutandoAcao;
         }

         //Executa o código de acordo com a ação atual.
         //No final da ação defina a variável State para RequerAcao.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Inteligencia artificial para jogos é uma serie de padrões executando para determinadas ações, não vale usar machine-learning ou deep-learning, Eu faria algo assim

```
bool acao = false;

void Update(){
  if(!acao && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < 5){
    Atacar();
    acao = true;
  }else if(!acao && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > 50){
    AvançarNoPlayer();
    acao = true;
  }
}

void Atacar(){
 // Atacar
 acao = false; 
}

void AvançarNoPlayer(){
 // AvançarNoPlayer
 acao = false; 
}
```

e por ai vai