# O que é o Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: framework, inteligência-artificial

Estava navegando no [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br) e visualizei  o 
[Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/).

Tenho duas perguntas:

**O que é Microsoft Bot Framework e para que serve?**

Realmente o nome já e bem intuitivo mas acho que seria legal ter informações e detalhes em português sobre esse **Framework**.

Comment: Pra causar polêmica na internet :P

Comment: Da [página de documentação](http://docs.botframework.com/) do próprio site (em tradução livre): "O Microsoft Bot Framework fornece exatamente o que você precisa para construir e conectar bots inteligentes (também chamados de [agentes](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80614/73)) que interagem naturalmente com os seus usuários onde quer que eles estejam conversando, desde texto/sms até Skype, Slack, Office 365 mail e outros serviços populares."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O nome diz tudo: um robô.

Um robô realiza algumas ações automaticamente, como ler e interpretar mensagens do usuário, monitorar salas de chat, enviar mensagens agendadas, e assim por diante. [Aqui tem a documentação](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted/).

Os robôs são escritos em C#. Há um tipo especial de projeto no Visual Studio para Bots. Podem ser integrados ao Skype, ao Slack, SMS, E-Mail, Telegram...

Na data desta resposta, é um *preview*. No futuro, acredito que essa tecnologia poderá ser bem madura e ter mais funcionalidades. Estarei editando esta resposta se isso ocorrer.

Answer (score 4):

É um framework (ou seja, oferece abstrações sob as quais você programa) para criação de chatbots (são softwares que funcionam dentro de apps de mensagens; veja mais [aqui](http://chatbotsbrasil.take.net/afinal-o-que-e-um-chatbot/)).

A Microsoft disponibiliza SDKs em C# e Javascript, e permite conectar seu chatbot (uma única implementação) em vários apps de mensagens, como Skype, Facebook Messenger, Telegram, Web, SMS, E-mail, etc.

No mercado nacional, com documentação em português e funcionalidades semelhantes,  você pode experimentar o [Blip](http://blip.ai).

Comment: Muito interessante , obrigado pela resposta !